# Photoshop & Wine not working

Tags: 14.04, photoshop

I tried to install Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried both Wine from Terminal and PlayOnLinux but at the end of the setup it showed an error.

I did read on the web that if it shows an error it was installed correctly.

So I looked at Program Files & Program Files (x86) but nothing here :(

Sorry for bad grammar, I'm Spanish.

Comment: I would advice to stay away from wine. Install Windows if you want to run Windows software. Dual boot or virtual. Otherwise learn to use Gimp.

Comment: I couldn't use Photoshop under Wine in Ubuntu either. But i did in openSUSE and Fedora quite successfully.

Answer (score 1):

*I want to make this clear first by saying that **i have never tried Photoshop on Wine** but in years my Wine can play games can execute almost any software and many thing due to the good configuration that i have made and of course the changes that the community made over the years, so with this in mind you can try to configure your Wine according to mine.*

*Is not bad to do other thing beyond photoshop right?*

There are four main reason that probably photoshop is not working:

**1.** Try the latest Wine see how: *https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu*

To find out your version type in terminal: wine --version

*Remove the older version first **IF** you using an older version before you install the new one.

**2.** Open **winetricks** and check what you are missing to make photoshop work:

Choose "**Select the default wineprefix**" click OK and then "**Install a Windows DLL or component**" click OK

See if you got those:

directx 9&10&11,
devenum,
directmusic,
directplay,
dmsynth,
dotnet,
dsound,
dxdiag,
gdplus,
msc42,
msctf,
msls31,
msvcirt,
msxml3,
msxml4,
pngfilt,
quartz,
riched20,
riched30,
vb6run,
vcrun2005,
vcrun2008,
vcrun2010,
vcrun2012,
vcrun2013,
vcrun6,
wininet,
wsh56vb,
xact,
xact_jun2010,
xinput,
xmllite.

Now click on Cancel and choose "**Change settings**" and enable "**ddr=opengl**" now press cancel a couple of times until the Winetricks quits.

**3.** Check the paths in Wine menu configuration:

**Note:** If you installed the new version of Wine open your file manager and choose to **view hidden folders** and go to directory */home/yourusername/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32* and make a shortcut of the file " winecfg.exe" on your desktop or run it from terminal by typing winecfg

Now at Tab "**Desktop Integration**" and also the tab "**Drives**" are the paths-folders as it should be?

**4.** Use Wine as "**Windoze xp**" from tab "**Applications**.

**Tip:** Remember to backup your .wine folder from directory */home/yourusername* **so you don't need to do all this everytime**, also you can use the folder for feature use and also for sharing with other users.

Now always make sure to scan time to time this folder with clamtk-gnome (Nautilus Menu Provider extension ) & [clamtk](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/) (the [clamav](http://www.clamav.net/) front-end) and everytime you download an *.exe file.

You can find **clamav** & **clamtk** & **clamtk-gnome** in Synaptic Package Manager and always keep up with latest Virus Definitions by typing in terminal: sudo freshclam